# Retry the try block in try-catch in java

Tags: java

I am new to java and have the following question. I have found a couple of answers on this but still am not clear how to implement the **while block** to solve the problem:

In the below code, I am trying to receive info about 'product name' and 'price' from the user input. product name is a string retrieved using the scanner.next() function and price is a double. If user gives product name incorrectly like with using a space, an error is thrown by scanner class which I catch in the catch block. 
Question is how can I go back to the try block and give the user a second chance at inputting the product name value instead of exiting from the system? I did a lot of search on this problem but still haven't found a solution.

```
String[] sArrProdName = new String[newUser.getNumberOfItemsInStock()] ;
    double[] sArrPrice = new double[newUser.getNumberOfItemsInStock()];

    for(int i=0;i<newUser.getNumberOfItemsInStock();i++)
    {
        try {

        System.out.println("Enter product Name: ");
        sArrProdName[i]= s.next();
        System.out.println("Price? : ");
        sArrPrice[i] = s.nextDouble();

        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) {

            prompt("Enter product name correctly");

        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using an infinite loop (or limited for loop) with a `break` statement in the `try` block ? Or a loop with a boolean that is set to `true` in the `try` block ? You should be able to do this on your own with these hints

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: If you are using this under a function than its better to throw  InputMismatchException e on function and catch it where you call this method instead in a for loop

Comment: In the catch block, decrement i, such as "i--".  Based on your for loop, that will undo the i++ part and give the user another chance.

Comment: I tried this but with no success:

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote this up on the fly, but the setup would look something like this:

```
String[] sArrProdName = new String[newUser.getNumberOfItemsInStock()] ;
    double[] sArrPrice = new double[newUser.getNumberOfItemsInStock()];

    for(int i=0;i<newUser.getNumberOfItemsInStock();i++)
    {
        boolean retryInput = true;

        while (retryInput)
        {
            try {

            System.out.println("Enter product Name: ");
            sArrProdName[i]= s.next();
            System.out.println("Price? : ");
            sArrPrice[i] = s.nextDouble();
            retryInput = false;
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException e) {

                prompt("Enter product name correctly");

            }
        }
    }
```

The basic premise here is that the try block can be thought of as its own self-contained `if` statement - `if` the task being tried was accomplished, execute the rest of the block. Therefore, a simple Boolean flag can be set to only change once the code is validated.

There are, of course, checks you would want to do before `retryInput = false;` itself; that's *only* there as a demonstration of where to change the Boolean flag.

EDIT: Shoutout to Dici, their comment is correct.

Comment: Same comments as for the other answer

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers. My final code works

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work:

```
class ProductInfo{
    public static final int NUM_RETRY = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] sArrProdName = new String[newUser.getNumberOfItemsInStock()] ;
        double[] sArrPrice = new double[newUser.getNumberOfItemsInStock()];
        int cont;
        for(int i=0;i<newUser.getNumberOfItemsInStock();i++){
            cont = 0;
            while (cont<=NUM_RETRY){
                try {
                    System.out.println("Enter product Name: ");
                    sArrProdName[i]= s.next();
                    System.out.println("Price? : ");
                    sArrPrice[i] = s.nextDouble();
                }catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                    cont++;
                    prompt("Enter product name correctly");

                }
            }
        }  

    }
}
```

Comment: User experience improvement: the last failure should make it clear that it can't be retried rather than outputting `Enter product name correctly` and then exit the program. You could also display the number of remaining retries after the first failure

Comment: This definitely works. Scotts solution also works wherein it loops correctly. Next problem I have is the product name is getting skipped and I get output to enter price directly:

Comment: Is there a way to clear the Scanner buffer so it doesn't take last remaining input in the next trial. Like in this case if previour user input that caused failure was 'ab an' then scanner.next() seems to be internally taking ' an' for the next try and skipping the Enter product name: output

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/bnsd55/RetryCatch

Example:

```
RetryCatch retryCatchSyncRunnable = new RetryCatch();
        retryCatchSyncRunnable
                // For infinite retry times, just remove this row
                .retryCount(3)
                // For retrying on all exceptions, just remove this row
                .retryOn(ArithmeticException.class, IndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
                .onSuccess(() -> System.out.println("Success, There is no result because this is a runnable."))
                .onRetry((retryCount, e) -> System.out.println("Retry count: " + retryCount + ", Exception message: " + e.getMessage()))
                .onFailure(e -> System.out.println("Failure: Exception message: " + e.getMessage()))
                .run(new ExampleRunnable());
```

Insted of ExampleRunnable you can write your own anonymous function

Answer (score 0):

```
A: while(true) {
                try {
                    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("How old are you?");
                    age = input.nextInt();
                    input.close();
                    break;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("You need to enter an integer!");
                    break;
                }
                finally{
                    if (age == 0)
                        continue A;
                }
            }
```

Comment: I had an int age = 0; Down and dirty but an if statement in finally with a continue and a loop block label works. Certainly there is a nicer way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a library called [unreliable](https://github.com/jaksa76/unreliable) that could help you here:

```java
    String[] sArrProdName = new String[newUser.getNumberOfItemsInStock()] ;
    double[] sArrPrice = new double[newUser.getNumberOfItemsInStock()];

    for(int i=0;i<newUser.getNumberOfItemsInStock();i++)
    {        
        System.out.println("Enter product Name: ");
        sArrProdName[i]= s.next();

        Unreliable.keepTrying(() -> {
            System.out.println("Price? : ");
            sArrPrice[i] = s.nextDouble();
        });        
    }
```

there are other similar methods in the library that allow you to specify number of retries, exceptions to ignore etc.